# Is there any French music that sounds remotely like KISS?

Tags: musique

My primary method for learning a language is through music—one of my greatest passions. Since I’m an avid Kiss fan, I’d like to know if there’s any French hard rock or metal like them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about the language.

Comment: Great unusual question, very subjectively, I'd suggest Trust. A French hard rock group. Same period, but as far Kiss was probably far right, politically, Trust was leftmost (but not punk). https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=WfD8Dnh2xho

Comment: But yes @Lambie is right...

Comment: @lemon Yeah, I was unsure whether I should ask this here or not. Thanks for the response, though!

Comment: @ND523 a compilation of the seventies here http://fouderock.com/rock_fr/rock_70.html